# Show contacts images when multiple contacts are selected, Android

Tags: android

I am trying to add this functionality.

[image]

I crated a activity in which i am showing map. And in another activity i am showing all the contacts with check-box and done button. I am able to get multiple contacts when click on Done. But i dont know how to implement below functionality.

According to me i need to add '+' image button on bottom of map, when i click that, then i need to open contact selection activity. When user click on 'Done' button then i sill show those contacts images at the bottom of map.

My code for multiple contacts selection is like bellow.

[multiple select contact listview](http://mobilesdevelopment.com/how-to-create-multiple-select-listview-with-custom-adapter-in-andorid/)